# SideBySide issue with ArcGISRuntime SDK version100.11

Tags: dll, side-by-side, arcgis-runtime

Trying to update my WPF application from the ArcGIS Runtime SDK version 100.6 to 100.11. I used the existing style in the WiX package to update the dll's so that all I had to do was ensure all the shader .cso files were accurate in the Components. Here is the screen shot of my dll's that are configured:
[image: screenshot of components]

When I try to run the application, I get an error that it cannot access the RuntimeCoreNet100_11.dll. In the Event Viewer I get the following message:
[image: Event Viewer error]
In running the SxsTrace program, for the runtimecoreAssembly, it states the Parser "Did not find manifest for culture Neutral".
Any help here would be very appreciated.

**Update**
per the instructions given in the comment, i added the manifest file to the dependency components in the component group pictured above. this allowed my app to start, but immediately crashed with a KERNELBASE.dll error. Anyone familiar with fixing those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the manifest files. There should be 4 files to deploy to each clientXX folder: runtimecore.dll, runtimecoreAssembly.manifest, RuntimeCoreNet100_11.dll and RuntimeCoreNet100_11.WPF.dll

Comment: i have the manifest file, but it wasnt ever included before in the WiX package. Do I add that as a regular Component in there?

Comment: Added the runtimecoreAssembly.manifest as a component in the DependencyComponents pictured above. this works to start the application but it immediately crashes with a KernelBase.dll error in the event viewer. any ideas where to go from there?

Comment: Hard to tell without more information about the crash. Does the app run from the output folder on the same device? If so probably an installer issue, so compare with what the installer lays down vs what visual studio outputs

Comment: turns out that besides the manifest, there was a resource path named 'network_analyst' that needed to be included in the Dependency components and a bin file inside of that. once i included those i was able to run my WiX package and the resulting application.